# Perform an aggregation over the past x months on a pandas df with start/end date ranges and a random reference date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, intervals, aggregation

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with contiguous `start_date` and `end_date` ranges and a a single `ref_date` for each user:

```
users = {'user_id': ['A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B'],
         'start_date': ['2017-03-07', '2017-03-12', '2017-04-04', '2017-05-22', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-23', '2018-12-29'],
         'end_date': ['2017-03-11', '2017-04-03', '2017-05-21', '2222-12-31', '2018-12-22', '2018-12-28', '2222-12-31'],
         'status': ['S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S3', 'S1', 'S2', 'S1'],
         'score': [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 900, 900, 1500],
         'ref_date': ['2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2019-01-19', '2019-01-19', '2019-01-19']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(users, columns = ['user_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'status', 'score', 'ref_date'])
```

```
print(df)

  user_id  start_date    end_date status  score    ref_date
0       A  2017-03-07  2017-03-11     S1   1000  2017-05-22
1       A  2017-03-12  2017-04-03     S2   1000  2017-05-22
2       A  2017-04-04  2017-05-21     S1   1000  2017-05-22
3       A  2017-05-22  2222-12-31     S3   1000  2017-05-22
4       B  2018-12-01  2018-12-22     S1    900  2019-01-19
5       B  2018-12-23  2018-12-28     S2    900  2019-01-19
6       B  2018-12-29  2222-12-31     S1   1500  2019-01-19
```

I would like to calculate a number of key figures per user for the last x months (x=1, 3, 6, 12) **before each  ref_date**, examples are:

- the number of days with status S1, S2, S3 in the last x months before
  `ref_date`
- the number of score increases in the last x months before `ref_date`
- the average daily score in the last x months before `ref_date`

The result should look like that (I hope I did the calculations correctly):

```
user_id    ref_date  nday_s1_last3m  nday_s2_last3m  nday_s3_last3m  \
0       A  2017-05-22            53              23               0   
1       B  2019-01-19            43               6               0   

   ninc_score_last3m  avg_score_last3m  
0                  0           1000.00  
1                  1           1157.14
```

The problem is that `ref_date` - x months could end up between an existing `start_date`/`end_date` interval or even before the first `start_date`, in which case the time "starts" on the first `start_date`. Resampling works, but creates huge dataframes if one has millions of users and many date ranges; I run out of memory. Any suggestions?

A detail to note: *before* a `ref_date` means up to and including `ref_date-1`

Comment: IIUC, start_date would be now (ref_date -x). And total_days will be new_start_date - end_date? Am I on track or is it something else?

Comment: Correct, start_date would be `ref_date`-x (or more precisely max(first `start_date`, `ref_date`-x). Then total_days will be `ref_date` - new_start_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first compute the real start and end dates, as respectively the higher and lower of start_date and ref_date minus 3 months, and end_date and ref_date. Once this is done, the number of days, score increases and average will be simple to compute:

Code could be:

```
# convert date columns to datetimes
for col in ['start_date', 'end_date', 'ref_date']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

# compute ref_date minus 3 months
ref = df.ref_date - pd.offsets.MonthOffset(3)

# compute the real start and end dates
tmp = df.loc[(df.end_date >= ref)&(df.start_date < df.ref_date),
             ['start_date', 'end_date']].copy()
tmp.loc[df.start_date < ref, 'start_date'] = ref-pd.Timedelta('1D')
tmp.loc[df.end_date >= df.ref_date, 'end_date'] = df.ref_date-pd.Timedelta('1D')

# add the relevant columns to the temp dataframe
tmp['days'] = (tmp.end_date - tmp.start_date).dt.days + 1
tmp['score'] = df.score
tmp['status'] = df.status

# build a list of result fields per user
data =[]
for i in df.user_id.unique():
    # user_id, ref_date
    d = [i, df.loc[df.user_id == i, 'ref_date'].iat[0]]
    data.append(d)
    # extract data for that user
    x = tmp[df.loc[tmp.index,'user_id'] == i]
    # number of days per status
    d.extend(x.groupby('status')['days'].sum().reindex(df.status.unique())
          .fillna(0).astype('int').tolist())
    # increase and average score
    d.extend((np.sum(np.where(x.score > x.score.shift(), 1, 0)),
          np.average(x.score, weights=x.days)))


# build the resulting dataframe
resul = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['user_id', 'ref_date', 'nday_s1_last3m',
                                    'nday_s2_last3m', 'nday_s3_last3m',
                                    'ninc_score_last3m', 'avg_score_last3m'])
```

It gives as expected:

```
  user_id   ref_date  nday_s1_last3m  nday_s2_last3m  nday_s3_last3m  ninc_score_last3m  avg_score_last3m
0       A 2017-05-22              53              23               0                  0       1000.000000
1       B 2019-01-19              43               6               0                  1       1157.142857
```

Comment: Thanks Serge. I'll try to see if I can somehow "vectorize" parts of this operation. Looping over the users seems to be very time consuming.